# Selection Sort for strings and integers at the same time

Tags: arrays, file, sorting, selection-sort

Here is the task I have been set with:

Create a text file named Names_ages.txt with the following content:

```
Jones 14
Abrams 15
Smith 19
Jones 9
Alexander 22
Smith 20
Smith 17
Tippurt 42
Jones 2
Herkman 12
Jones 11
```

Each line is a person’s last name followed by a space and then his age. We want to sort these names alphabetically and in the case of duplicate names, sort by age in an ascending fashion. A properly sorted list will appear as follows:

```
Abrams, 15
Alexander, 22
Herkman, 12
Jones, 2
Jones, 9
Jones, 11
Jones, 14
Smith, 17
Smith, 19
Smith, 20
Tippurt, 42
```

Here are my (working) selection sort methods for Strings and ints respectively:

```
private static void sort(String[] a) {

    String min;
    int minIndex;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        min = a[i];
        minIndex = i;
        // find minimum
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
            // salient feature
            if (a[j].charAt(0) < min.charAt(0)) {
                min = a[j];
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }
        a[minIndex] = a[i]; // swap
        a[i] = min;
    }

}

private static void sort(int[] a) {

    int min, minIndex;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        min = a[i];
        minIndex = i;
        // find minimum
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
            // salient feature
            if (a[j] < min) {
                min = a[j];
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }
        a[minIndex] = a[i]; // swap
        a[i] = min;
    }

}
```

I can sort the names in the text file and then the numbers after, but the ages end up corresponding with incorrect people. Here is my class with the main method:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Krish/IdeaProjects/Lessons/src/Lesson40/MultipleKey/NamesAges.txt"));
    String text[] = new String[100];
    int index = 0;

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        text[index++] = scanner.nextLine();
    }

    scanner.close();

    String name;
    String[] names = new String[index];
    int age;
    int[] ages = new int[index];

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        Scanner line = new Scanner(text[i]);
        name = line.next();
        names[i] = name;
        age = line.nextInt();
        ages[i] = age;
    }

    sort(names);
    sort(ages);

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        System.out.println(names[i] + ", " + ages[i]);
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a POJO class `Person` implementing `Comparable<Person>`
2. After parsing, store `Person` instances in a collection, say `List<Person>`
3. Sort the collection

-

```
public class PersonTest {
    static class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
        private static final Comparator<Person> COMPARATOR = Comparator
                .comparing(Person::getName)
                .thenComparingInt(Person::getAge);

        final String name;
        final int age;

        public static Person parse(String rec) {
            final String[] parts = rec.split(" ");
            return new Person(parts[0], Integer.valueOf(parts[1]));
        }

        Person(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Person o) {
            return COMPARATOR.compare(this, o);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testSorting() throws Exception {
        final Person[] sortedPersons = Files.lines(Paths.get("/path/to/file.txt"))
                .map(Person::parse)
                .sorted() // sort it here
                .toArray(Person[]::new);

        // or instead, sort it here with your custom algorithm
        // using Person.COMPARATOR for comparison
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really help. I need to fix my existing code so that it actually sorts properly using my selection sort methods.

Comment: But your code is fundamentally not partition correctly. It cannot be `sort(String[])` and `sort(int[])`, it has to be `sort(Person[])` or sort(Pair<String, Integer>[])`, etc.

Comment: Yeah, well that's the thing. I have to sort them using these selection sort methods and/or find a way to edit the methods so that it sorts both the names and the ages at the same time. I can't use any other class such as Comparable to help me sort it; have to use my own selection sort method.

Comment: `Comparable` is only a clean way to abstract out the `<` operator, so a single implementation of the sorting algorithm can sort anything that _is sortable using pairwise comparison_. All you need is to change your algorithm (take either `String[]` or `int[]` version as a base) to take `? extends Comparable<T>` as an argument and use `a.compareTo(b)` instead of `<` for comparison.

Comment: I understand your point, but the task specifically says to not use the Comparable interface and to make your own selection sort methods instead.

Comment: You can use the `Person.COMPARATOR`, then it won't be "using the `Comparable`", but you will need a layer of comparator abstaction in order to be able to compare Person with Person using two fields, one way or another. Then why not doing it the correct Java way.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Krish/IdeaProjects/Lessons/src/Lesson40/MultipleKey/NamesAges"));
    String[] text = new String[100];
    int index = -1;

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        text[++index] = scanner.nextLine();
    }

    scanner.close();

    Scanner line;
    String[] name = new String[100];
    int[] age = new int[100];

    for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
        line = new Scanner(text[i]);
        name[i] = line.next();
        age[i] = line.nextInt();
    }

    String minName;
    int minAge;
    int minIndex;

    for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
        minName = name[i];
        minAge = age[i];
        minIndex = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= index; j++) {
            if (name[j].compareTo(minName) == 0) {
                if (age[j] < minAge) {
                    minName = name[j];
                    minAge = age[j];
                    minIndex = j;
                }
            } else if (name[j].compareTo(minName) < 0) {
                minName = name[j];
                minAge = age[j];
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }
        name[minIndex] = name[i];
        name[i] = minName;
        age[minIndex] = age[i];
        age[i] = minAge;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j <= index; j++) {
        System.out.println(name[j] + ", " + age[j]);
    }

}
```